# Looking for SSIS ETL Architecture Patterns

Tags: ssis

I am working on the design of an ETL solution that imports a large amount of files into database tables every hour. The files are being dropped in a network share.

I like to have multiple SSIS servers running the same package and import the files from the network share. This way, I can distribute the load across multiple servers and improve the availability of the overall solution. Also, I can add more SSIS ETL servers to the solution anytime the load increases.

As simple as above requirement looks, it needs many important design details to be addressed including the items below:

- How to make sure two SSIS servers do not take the same file concurrently and import it.
- If an SSIS server crashes while it is importing a data file, then how can my design assure the other SSIS server can take the file and finishes it? And the half-processed-file will not be abandoned?

I expect above requirements are quite typical with many ETL design architectures. I wonder there is an architecture pattern to address the requirements I explained above.

Comment: This might be helpful https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: @RichardCL, the design that you've described imposes many points of failures. Are you suggesting that scaling out is not a good architecture pattern for ETL system?

Comment: @RichardCL, according to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213127(v=sql.110).aspx  "Clustering Integration Services is not recommended because the Integration Services service is not a clustered or cluster-aware service"

Comment: @AllanXu you might want to look into the Always On Availability Groups feature in SQL Server 2016. You can add the SSIS catalog (SSISDB) to an Always On Availability Group. MSDN > Always On for SSIS Catalog (SSISDB): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt163864.aspx